# My Sharepoint wikipage does not show the same in Internet Explorer as in Edge

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki

Below i have a picture of a Sharepoint Blog shown with Internet Explorer.
[image]

Now i have created to same layout on a Sharepoint Wikipage using the component Table.
When I display my wikipage in Microsoft Edge i get to see the border and the shade of the layout
Just like i wanted it. But when i use Internet Explorer, I see the border of the layout but not the shade. While the orginal Sharepoint Blog does show the border and shade in Internet Explorer.
What am i missing here? Does someone one know the solution? Thank uou in advanced. Gr. P.

This is my CSScode which is linked to the Sharepoint wikipage:

```
.ms-rteTable-default {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); //works in EDGE but not in IE
}

.ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > th, .ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > td  {
  border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;  //works in EDGE and IE
}

.ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > th {
  border-top-right-radius:5px;   //works in IE but not in EDGE
  border-top-left-radius:5px;    //works in IE but not in EDGE
}

.ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > td  {
  padding: 35px 70px 35px 35px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;  //works in IE but not in EDGE
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;   //works in IE but not in EDGE
}
```

Greetings P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE do not support box-shadow.
[image]
You could take a reference to this question:
[CSS Box-Shadow Not Working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949396/css-box-shadow-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Thank you for the info. Gr. P.